# Should I install Microsoft Security Essentials on Windows 8 Developer Preview? 

Tags: windows, security, ms-security-essentials, windows-8-preview

Does Windows 8 Developer Preview come pre-installed with anti-virus software?

I'm testing Windows 8 on my laptop and it's running great; I just want to make sure it's secure.

Should I install Microsoft Security Essentials on Windows 8 Developer Preview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8 Developer Preview comes with the new MSE which is renamed to the old name Windows Defender. Under the Action center's virus section, it says Windows Defender is the provider. If you look at the name of the executable file of the Windows Defender in task manager, it says MsMpEng.exe, same as Security Essentials.

There is no need to install the old MSE on the developer preview for virus protection.

Comment: ! Oh really ? do you have an material citing this ? i would be more than happy to award the answer to you if this is the case.

Comment: On the Windows 8 Blog, they highlighted the new features of Windows Defender, which sounds like they integrated MSE functionality into it.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 8 Developer Preview comes with the old Windows Defender, not as good as MSE, I installed MSE on my W8 install.

.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Avast AV without any problems ...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have issued a KB which puts a hard block on the installation of MSE on the Windows 8 Consumer Preview. [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2685194).

This would suggest that it conflicts with the built-in Windows Defender, and that MSE is redundant.